# Error con manejo de ficheros - UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 3: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, archivo, utf-8

Estoy resolviendo un ejercicio de ficheros. El mismo trata sobre la creación y manipulación de un archivo "listin.txt" en el cual se almacenan nombres y números de teléfonos.
El programa debe ser capaz de:

1. Verificar si existe el fichero. De no existir, crearlo.
2. Poder agregar nuevos números.
3. Consultar números
4. Eliminar números

Este es el código:

```
class Listin:
    
    def __init__(self,listin):
        
        self.listin = listin
        self.menu()
        
    def menu(self):
        print(f"Menu de opciones:\n"  \
              f"---------------------\n" \
              f"Verificar la existencia del fichero:\t 1\n" \
              f"Añadir fono:\t\t\t\t 2\n" \
              f"Consultar fono:\t\t\t\t 3\n" \
              f"Eliminar fono:\t\t\t\t 4\n" \
              f"Salir:\t\t\t\t\t 0")
        opcion = input("\nIngrese el número de la operación que desea realizar: ")
        
        if int(opcion) == 1:
            self.verificarFichero()
        elif int(opcion) == 2:
            nombre = input("\nIngrese nombre del nuevo usuario: ")
            fono = input("Ingrese fono del nuevo usuario: ")
            self.añadirFono(nombre,fono)
        elif int(opcion) == 3:
            nombre = input("\nIngrese nombre del usuario: ")
            self.consultarFono(nombre)
        elif int(opcion) == 4:
            nombre = input("\nIngrese nombre del usuario: ")
            self.eliminarFono(nombre)
        elif int(opcion) == 0:
            print("\nEl programa se ha cerrado")
    
    def verificarFichero(self):
        import os
        if os.path.isfile(self.listin) is True:
            print(f"\nEl archivo {self.listin} ya existe")
        else:
            fichero = open(self.listin,"w", encoding = 'utf8')
            fichero.close()
            print(f"\nSe a creado el fichero {self.listin}") 
    
    def añadirFono(self,nombre,fono):
        fichero = open(self.listin,"a")
        fichero.write(f"{nombre},{fono}\n")
        fichero.close()
        print(f"\nSe ha incorporado el usuario : {nombre}")
    
    def consultarFono(self,nombre):
        fichero = open("listin.txt","r", encoding = 'utf8')
        texto = fichero.read().split("\n")
        fichero.close()
        
        aux = []
        for i in texto:
            aux.append(i.split(","))
        
        for i in range(len(aux)):
            if nombre == aux[i][0]:
                print(f"\nEl numero del usuario ingresado es: {aux[i][1]}")
    
    def eliminarFono(self, nombre):
        fichero = open("listin.txt","r", encoding = 'utf8')
        texto = fichero.readlines()
        fichero.close()
        
        aux = []
        for i in texto:
            if nombre not in i:
                aux.append(i)
        
        fichero2 = open("listin.txt","w")
        for k in aux:
            fichero2.write(f"{k}")
        fichero2.close()
        print("\nOperación realizada con éxito")
        
listin = Listin("listin.txt")
```

Todo funciona bien hasta que incorporo algún usuario cuyo nombre lleve un acento. Ahí se va todo al carajo jaja. Como pueden ver le metí "encoding = 'utf8'" en todas partes en donde pude a ver si se arreglaba el asunto pero sigue sin funcionar.
El error que me tira es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así que esa es mi consulta básicamente.¿Qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal?.
De antemano muchas gracias!!. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al leer tu explicación, cae de su propio peso que no agregaste el `utf8` en todos lados. Por tu misma explicación, el primer lugar que busqué fue el que utilizas para agregar un nuevo registro (el que tiene acento y hace que todo casque).

Así ví que, en el método `añadirFono`, lo abres para escritura con la codificación default, que no es utf8. En mi equipo, por ejemplo, es ANSI 1252 (Windows 1252). Cambia la apertura, por ejemplo a:

```
    def añadirFono(self, nombre, fono):
        fichero = open(self.listin, "a", encoding = 'utf8')
        fichero.write(f"{nombre},{fono}\n")
        fichero.close()
        print(f"\nSe ha incorporado el usuario : {nombre}")
```

No seguí revisando, considero que es tu tarea, revisa de nuevo y debes asegurarte que en todos los casos se abra con la misma codificación el archivo.

Comment: Era eso!!!!! Claaaro, no había agregado 'utf8' en todos lados jaja XD. Muchisimas gracias!!!

Comment: Me alegra ser de ayuda. Considera marcar la respuesta como aceptada, pues esto ayudará en el futuro a quienes lleguen aquí a identificar que la respuesta **si** fue de ayuda. Recuerda que en StackOverflow puedes saber, de esta manera, si hubo una respuesta útil y cuál es. Es muy útil cuando llegas aquí googlando un proximo problema. Esto no resta mérito a otras respuestas y en ocasiones habrá buenas o hasta mejores respuestas no aceptadas, pero si que ayuda. Si no sabes como aceptar una respuesta, haz el [tour].

Comment: No tenía idea de lo de aceptar XD!. Ahí le mande ;)… Y gracias de nuevo!